Disabling Laravel Session and XSRF-TOKEN Cookies on Guest Pages for Cloudfront Caching
PHP: 8.2
Laravel Framework: 11
We're aiming to leverage Cloudfront to cache our blog posts. Ideally, when a guest visits /posts/news-item-1, we want to include Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public headers to enable Cloudfront caching for the content. However, for logged-in users, the content needs to remain private and uncachable. Here's the caveat: we still require session and cookie functionality for other pages and functionalities within the application.
To achieve this, we're looking to implement middleware to conditionally disable the laravel_session and XSRF-TOKEN cookies specifically on guest pages. While we have a working solution, we believe there might be a more elegant and streamlined approach.
PageSpeed.php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class PageSpeed
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        // Logic to disable cookies, Auth::check() etc...
        $request->merge(['cdn_cache' => true]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}

VerifyCsrfToken.php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    public function shouldAddXsrfTokenCookie()
    {
        if ($this->app->request->get('cdn_cache')) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->addHttpCookie;
    }
}

StartSession.php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession as Middleware;

class StartSession extends Middleware
{

    protected function handleStatefulRequest(Request $request, $session, Closure|\Closure $next)
    {
        $request->setLaravelSession(
            $this->startSession($request, $session)
        );

        $this->collectGarbage($session);

        $response = $next($request);

        $this->storeCurrentUrl($request, $session);

        if (!$request->get('cdn_cache')) {
            $this->addCookieToResponse($response, $session);
        }

        $this->saveSession($request);

        return $response;
    }
}


While our original solution addressed the question, it's not a great solution due to security concerns like session token leaks. Here's a more secure approach:
Separate CDN Routes:

Create a dedicated route file (e.g., routes/cdn.php) containing only
the routes you intend to serve through the CDN.
These routes should not utilize any default Laravel middleware that might introduce session variables or unnecessary security checks.

The provided code snippet demonstrates this concept effectively, separating CDN routes into a distinct file (routes/cdn.php).
// bootstrap/app.php
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
    api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
    commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
    // channels: __DIR__.'/../routes/channels.php',
    health: '/up',
    then: function () {
      Route::name('cdn.')
        ->group(base_path('routes/cdn.php'));
    },
  )

 // routes/cdn.php
 Route::get('news/{slug}', [PostController::class, 'show`']);

Cloudfront Configuration:

Set up a default path pattern in Cloudfront with caching disabled
(Managed-CachingDisabled / Managed-AllViewerExceptHostHeader). This
ensures dynamic content from your Laravel application isn't cached.
Configure a separate path pattern specifically for your CDN routes
(e.g., /news/*).

Set caching to Managed-CachingOptimized for
efficient content delivery.
Disable the Origin request policy to prevent unnecessary requests to your Laravel origin server.



